# When my TinyMCE plugin inserts a tag into the edit box, typed-in text appears inside that tag instead of outside. How do I avoid this?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I am using the plugin here for TinyMCE mentions so when I type @ it shows JSON results and i can select from the list.

https://github.com/StevenDevooght/tinyMCE-mention

I added this code, which returns the selected value and name in a `<span>` html tag:

```
insert: function(item) {
    return '<span class="mention" id="' + item.sequence + '">@' + item.name + '</span>';
},
```

Problem is, it’s inserting the selected value as expected, but when I continue typing in the textarea, it remains inside the value of the `<span>` tag.

Once the item has been selected, I want to continue the typing outside of the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly a fix, more of a silly workaround:

```
insert: function(item) {
    return ('<span class="mention" id="' + item.sequence + '">@'
        + item.name + '</span>&zwnj;');
},
```

This will insert a U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER code point after the `<span>` element, which will force the caret to appear outside the element. Any ‘dummy’ character would do; the original library [does something similar](https://github.com/StevenDevooght/tinyMCE-mention/blob/8653f4908f5f83b3a0acf0216078641d70d3d3f9/mention/plugin.js#L320) (with `&nbsp;`) for what I assume is a similar reason. In fact, `&nbsp;` might even work better, as at least it is visible to the user, so they will not be surprised by an invisible character being deleted when they hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.